# Настройка роутера

Tags: веб-сервер, роутер

Помогите

Такая проблема. Есть два ПК они подключаються к интернету через WI-FI роутер Trendnet, но подключение к интернету происходит уже в роутере. Так вот такая задача как пробится из интернета к одному из ПК на котором установлен Web-сервер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NAT, PAT, virtual servers, port forwarding - что то из этого, настройте на вашем рутере. А так это все синонимы.

Comment: А что именно нужно там написать? Судя по названию я так понял что нужно прописать порт для локального ИП

Comment: И не просто порт, а его отображение на конкретный внутренний адрес:порт. Подсказка есть здесь: http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%CF%EE%F0%F2/Forwarding

Answer (score 3):

дам более конкретную подсказку, нужно в гугле написать:

```
trendnet <модель роутера> port forwarding
```